# Linq, select differences between two lists, select same between same list, and select duplicates same list

Tags: c#, linq, list, merge, equality

I want to know if it's possible in LINQ to achieve something along the lines of:

```
newList: { [1], [2] }
oldList: { [2], [3], [4], [5] }
resultantList = { [1], [2, 2], [3], [4], [5] }
```

Ok that was an oversimplification. Lets say:

```
Class A
{
    public string Name;
    public IList<B> Items;
    public bool Equals(A obj)
    {
         return obj.Name == Name;
    }
}


newList<A> = {{ Name = "A", Items[1]}, { Name = "B", Items[1] }}
oldList<A> = {{ Name = "C", Items[2]}, { Name = "A", Items[2] }, { Name = "D", Items[1] }, { Name = "E", Items[1] },}
mergedList<A> = {{ Name = "A", Items[3]}, { Name = "B", Items[1]}, { Name = "C", Items[2]}, { Name = "D" , Items[1]}, { Name = "E" , Items[1]}}
```

Notice that for the instance with Name="A" the list is actually the merged list of both lists. Order doesn't matter and in reality the equality is more complex.

I wish to achieve this on types (i.e. below works, but would be inefficient):

```
var fragments = newGeometryFragments.Except(oldGeometryFragments).ToList();
fragments.AddRange(oldGeometryFragments.Except(newGeometryFragments).ToArray());
var mergedFragments = (from newGeometry in newGeometryFragments
                       from oldGeometry in oldGeometryFragments
                       where newGeometry.Equals(oldGeometry)
                       select MergeGeometryFragments(newGeometry, oldGeometry)).ToArray();
 fragments.AddRange(mergedFragments);
```

Comment: Is the order of items in the list relevant?

Comment: Search for Linq "Full outer join"

Comment: So you basically want a union, but with duplicate values shown by virtue of being in a two-element list?

Comment: Order is not relevant. Essentially what I want is a merge, where it concatenates items from two lists, and "merges" items that it detects are equivalent (i.e. the MergeGeometryFragments method).

Comment: It's almost a Union. Only I want it to call a method on items that it detects are present in both lists and return a set of the merged items.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code, assuming you have the `oldList` and `newList` already filled:

```
newList.Union(oldList) // unite the collections
   .GroupBy(x => x /*, ComparerInstance*/) // will group by unique elemens
   .Select(x => x.ToList()) // or .ToArray(), convert each group to array or list
   .ToList(); // return a list of lists/arrays
```

The code above will produce a list of collections. Each collection will have one or more equal elements, depending on how many times that element is present in `newList.Union(oldList)`.

If you are using specific elements and want to control the way they are compared (determined equal), pass a custom `IEqualityComparer<YourType>` instance to the `GroupBy` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an outer join:

```
var oldList = new List<int?> { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var newList = new List<int?> { 1, 2 };
var result = from all in oldList.Union(newList).OrderBy(num => num)
             join o in oldList on all equals o into gjOld
             from oldOuter in gjOld.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join n in newList on all equals n into gjNew
             from newOuter in gjNew.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { newVal = newOuter, oldVal = oldOuter };
```

This works also with a custom class when you implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`. Then the `Nullable<int>` trick is also unnecessary

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/GPaXSS)

```
newVal: 1   oldVal: 
newVal: 2   oldVal: 2
newVal:     oldVal: 3
newVal:     oldVal: 4
newVal:     oldVal: 5
```